# wrapfigure shifting the figure to the next section instead of wrapping the intended paragraph

Tags: sectioning, wrapfigure

This is where I want to wrap the figure:
[image]

But the figure is going to the next section(Reference) I don't know why:
[image]

I tried some of the solutions posted before but nothing seems to work in this case.
MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
% \usepackage{bbding} %
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for micro meter
\usepackage{amsmath} % for math fraction symbol
\usepackage{relsize} % for large summation
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek} % greek letters within text
\usepackage{bm} % bold math symbols
\usepackage{verbatim} % for commenting
\usepackage{lipsum} % for MWE
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} % for inline/margin comments that are visible in the pdf
% \usepackage{fixltx2e} % not needed anymore for subscript
% \usepackage{ulem} % for strikethrough: \sout{text} 
% the ulem package gives reference sections underlines so remove it if not used. Didn't research why... 
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % for quotes
% \usepackage{indentfirst} %indents beginning of the paragraph
\usepackage{hyperref} % for hyperlinks, citations
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=green,
    colorlinks=True,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={banikr_phd_thesis_proposal},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} } % folder where the images or figures are
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % make Figure 1 bold
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping a figure with words
\usepackage{enumerate}  
% +---------------------------+
% |  for white space removal  |
% +---------------------------+
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}
\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}
% +---------------------------+
% |    writing starts here    |
% +---------------------------+
\begin{document}
% \usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\section{Specific Aim 3}
    \lipsum[5]\cite{carreira2015large}. 
 atlases\cite{verbeeck2017connecting}.\lipsum[2].\\
   \lipsum[2]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[19]{r}{0.6\textwidth}
        \centering %8cm, height=6cm
        \includegraphics[width=9cm, height=6cm]{figures/blockface_screenshot.PNG} % scale=0.2 % width=\textwidth % this makes the figure same as caption width
        % \vspace*{-8mm}
        \caption{Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum. Nam dui
ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
Nam lacus libero}
        \label{blockface}
        % \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{15pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}
    \end{wrapfigure}
     \lipsum[2]\cite{attia2012monitoring}. \lipsum[2]\cite{MIRT} \lipsum[5]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[25]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=9cm]{figures/MR_MS.png}
        \caption{demo caption.}
        \label{mrms}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
    \newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} % this includes the reference section in the contents
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %abbrv %apalike %ieeetr
\bibliography{references}
\newpage
\section*{Supplementary information}
\label{sec:SI}
\todo[color=cyan!]{transfer all the materials to the corresponding sections. No need for SI}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Supplementary information}
    \subsection{Demo pca}
    The low-dimensional space acquired by PCA transformation can be visualized where all the pixels from different tissues are labeled by simple clustering method(i.e. 
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}[10]{0.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}%,margin=2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=8.0 cm, height=4.5 cm]{figures/PCA_agglomerative_clustering.png}
        \vspace*{-3mm}
        \caption{Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum. Nam dui
                ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero.}
        \label{pca agglom}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]. See \hyperref[pca agglom]{\textbf{Figure 11}} 
    \lipsum[4]
    \subsection{Demo demo}
    \lipsum[2] \hyperref[peptide umap]{\textbf{Figure 12}}, 
    \lipsum[9]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l!}[10]{0.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}%,margin=2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=8 cm, height=5.5 cm]{figures/peptide_UMAP_HDBSCAN.png}
        \vspace*{-3mm}
        \caption{Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum. Nam dui
                ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero.}
        \label{peptide umap}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \subsection{this is also demo}
\end{document}
```

The image is kind of vertically tall with more height than width in case needed.

Comment: I don't believe [l!] is a valid option.  Also, the text is supposed to go AFTER wrapfigure, not before.  And \subsection is definitly incompatible.

Comment: That last figure is not the concern actually. See the second wrapfigure from the top please. 
The first wrapfigure wraps perfectly.

Comment: Could you make your MWE a little more minimal?  There are 4 different wrapfigures and it is not apparent which one is bad or precisely how.  Also, since wrapfigure normally is at the start of a paragraph, try adding blank lines before and after.

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange... If I use \lipsum in \begin{minipage} it seems to work in MWE...

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}[25]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=9cm]{figures/MR_MS.png}
        \caption{demo caption.}
        \label{mrms}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{minipage}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
```

[image]

But when I use my own text or in this case, copy and paste the lipsum texts... it doesn't work anymore.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[25]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=9cm]{figures/MR_MS.png}
        \caption{demo caption.}
        \label{mrms}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{minipage}
        % \lipsum[2]
        Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus
        semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum,
        justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus.
        Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo.
        Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.
        Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vi-
        tae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non,
        nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus,
        magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem 
    \end{minipage}
```

[image]

I freaking hate Latex...